# Unable to retrieve the Azure Wiki page at 'Home Page/Page1/Page2/SpecificPage'. The returned HTTP code was '404'

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-devops-rest-api, azure-repos

**Issue:**

“Unable to retrieve the Azure Wiki page at 'Home Page/Page1/Page2/SpecificPage'. The returned HTTP code was '404'.”

**When this happens:**

Migrating a Wiki from Azure DevOps Server 2020 to “Azure DevOps Services”.
When executing the Pipeline with the exact same Jobs/Tasks Outputs this error when doing the REST API Call towards the wiki that contains the relevant information.

**Solutions Offered and Applied:**

Enabled a good quantity of permissions to "Azure DevOps Groups"
Enabled a good quantity of permissions from the "Wiki Security"

**Impact:**

Blocking our migration towards Azure DevOps Services
Pipeline get stuck attempting to retrieve the data from the pipeline

**New API Body to meet ADO services:**

```
Write-Host "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMFOUNDATIONSERVERURI)"
Write-Host "$($env:SYSTEM_TEAMPROJECTID)"
Write-Host "$(wiki-identifier)"
Write-Host "$(all-sites-wiki-page-path)"
Write-Host Set authorization headers
$Header = @{
Authorization = 'Bearer ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)"))
}
$params = @{ 
'Uri' = 'https://dev.azure.com/MyCollection/MyProject/_apis/wiki/wikis/MyWikiIdentifier.wiki/pages?path=Home%20Page%2FMy%20Wiki%2FPage%2FSubpage&includeContent=true&api-version=5.0'
'Headers' = $Header
'Method' = 'GET'
'ContentType' = 'application/json; charset=ASCII.GetBytes'
}
Write-Host Invoke REST API
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
Write-Host $Response
```

As a disclaimer I did test the Header part of the code with Bearer and Basic both fails:

```
Authorization = 'Bearer ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)"))
```

*And*

```
Authorization = 'Basic ' + [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN)"))
```

**Error Output with "Bearer":**

[image]

**Error Output with "Basic":**

```
Invoke-RestMethod : {"$id":"1","innerException":null,"message":"TF401019: The Git repository with name or identifier
0ea73a5d-4187-69c6-af49-d9a4573733ta does not exist or you do not have permissions for the operation you are 
attempting.","typeName":"Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server.GitRepositoryNotFoundException, 
Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Git.Server","typeKey":"GitRepositoryNotFoundException","errorCode":0,"eventId":3000}
At F:\AzureAgents\ServicesAgent01\_work\_temp\12319456-e600-1234-a872-dd6ed49e758f.ps1:18 char:13
$Response = Invoke-RestMethod @params
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation:
(System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-RestMethod], WebException
FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeRestMethodCommand
```

#### Latest news on this ticket:

Find out that the error is coming from the Persistent value "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" I did change for a PAT and the Authentication worked well "Retrieving the wiki content" but to simplify our code it would be preferable to use Persistent Data across all our Pipelines instead of PAT, so in order to do that which security values need to be granted so that the "SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" work in ADO Services?

**Here our Current Security Permissions:**

**Pipeline Security:**

Build_Administrators [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VNvmc.png)

Project_Administrators [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fIEdw.png)

Project_Collection_Administrators [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCmMP.png)

Project_Collection_Build_Administrators [5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yIbAP.png)

Project_Collection_Build_Service [6](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CX9KZ.png)

**At Collection Security** Level my user is part of:
"CollectionName Admins" . Therefore I should have propagated permissions across all the projects

What potentially Am I missing that the Persistent Data Token "env:SYSTEM_ACCESSTOKEN" isn't working? Really will appreciate the help of the community

Comment: Hi, is there any updates on this question? Please let me know whether my answer can help you~ If not, could you please provide a sample of your pipeline which caused the error so that people can further investigate the question.

Answer (score 0):

The probable cause of this problem is that you didn't change the REST API that calls the wiki pages.

In Azure DevOps Server, the REST API [Pages - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get?view=azure-devops-server-rest-5.0) is:

```
GET https://{instance}/{collection}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?api-version=5.0
```

In Azure DevOps Services, the REST API [Pages - Get Page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/wiki/pages/get%20page?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) is:

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/wiki/wikis/{wikiIdentifier}/pages?api-version=6.0
```

Comment: Hi @Jane Ma-MSFT, I did change the API Body to meet the ADO Services Structure but still failing, to develop further I have updated the publication to show the current Body of the API, potentially with that you or another member of the forum can spot an error that I haven't consider/understood

Comment: Hi @Jane Ma-MSFT, I found the reason why isn't working but no idea how to solve it: The "$env:SYSTEM_TOKEN" that isn't granting the necessary permissions, only worked via a PAT, but we would like to keep using Persistent data instead of PAT, did add to the current Ticket all our current permissions so that the community/you could help find if I'm missing security parameters and so forth...Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 settings that govern the permissions of the system access token. By default its permissions are somewhat limited to prevent people from abusing a pipeline to do actions they otherwise cannot do.

1. The project/collection setting on the pipeline will limit the access token to either the parent project of the pipeline or the whole project collection/azure DevOps organization.
2. The permissions of the service account. This depends on the setting you've picked in 1. For project scoped, use: `Your-project-name Build Service (your-collection-name)`, for collection scope: `Project Collection Build Service (your-collection)`.

You can add the abovementioned accounts to a security group to grant it additional permissions as well.

See:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#job-authorization-scope
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/access-tokens?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml#manage-build-service-account-permissions